# I get a null value for a non-nullable foreign key with the entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

What am I doing wrong? I mapped a SQL server database with the wizard. It's a rather complex database, but for this example we can assume three tables: REPORTROWS, REPORTCOLUMNS and REPORTNAMES. REPORTROWS has the following columns ID, RESULT, REPORTDATE, REPORTCOLUMNID, REPORTNAMEID. REPORTNAMES and REPORTCOLUMNS are very simple tables with ID, NAME. ID are always primary keys and REPORTCOLUMNSID and REPORTNAMESID are the foreign keys that link REPORTROWS with REPORTCOLUMNS and REPORTNAMES.

Now I populate the three tables with valid values (I do not violate any foreign key constraints). When I call the following code

```
var recs = from a in ctx.REPORTROWS
           where a.REPORTNAMES.NAME == "my report" && a.REPORTDATE == somedate select a;
```

I get the rows I want, but I cannot use the field a.REPORTCOLUMNS later in the code because it is null!! Why? REPORTCOLUMNID is defined as a non-nullable integer (that's why it's the foreign key). However, the  field a.REPORTNAMES is correct. a.REPORTDATE remains null even if I add `&& a.REPORTCOLUMNS != null` to the query.

I've seen links with similar questions but I couldn't find a definitive answer. Can anybody please help me. For your information, I am using .NET Framework 3.5 and I coulnd't check the "include foreign keys" in the wizard while mapping the database. It was grayed out (and I still don't understand why).

Thanks a lot in advance

It's the EF version v2.0.50727

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: You can't include foreign keys, when using wizard, because foreign key associations are supported since EF 4, which is shipped with .NET 4. That's why this option is grayed. You should either paste your model screenshot, or table definitions - it is hard to understand, where's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your REPORTCOLUMNS (and I believe, your REPORTNAMES) tables should be represented as entities in your context as well, right? I believe the error occurs because lazy loading is not enabled and you did not explicitly fetch the reportcolumns entity properties in your query.

You can try the following code or something similar:

```
var recs = from a in ctx.REPORTROWS.Include(r => r.REPORTCOLUMNS)
           where a.REPORTNAMES.NAME == "my report" && a.REPORTDATE == somedate select a;
```

The main thing is to do the "Include" method to get the Reportcolumn entity and its properties when you perform your query.

Another option is to explicitly specify a REPORTCOLUMNID property in your REPORTROWS entity that maps to the REPORTCOLUMNS primary key. You should be able to perform an "reportrow.REPORTCOLUMNID" to get the ID of the reportcolumn entity associated, but you won't be able to get the other properties until you query for it again.